How to change or permanently set background image(wallpaper) in openbox WM?
Hey I just installed Arch Linux in Virtualbox btw with openbox, gdm and rofi. I wanted to set a wallpaper for the background.
So, I added this line in the end of my /home/user/.bashrc file -
feh --bg-fill ~/wallpapers/squid-girl.png

The problem is that it doesn't set the wallpaper just after I successfully login in an openbox-session but after I open an terminal window in an openbox-session.
So, that is the matter. Now how am I supposed to/should set it?

Well, if you want something to be done for a bash shell, then put it in .bashrc, else, don't put it there :)
You will need to figure out how openbox auto-starts programs. Some description can be found here on the arch Linux wiki.

Okay right! I just had a bad tendency to put everything on the .bashrc. Adding the line in ~/.config/openbox/autostart did the work. :)   @Marcus Müller

I'd strongly recommend you put as little as possible in your .bashrc; as you can see, that's not the right place for most stuff, and also, it's executed every single time you start a shell. You don't want to set your background image 100 times a day, once is enough. Many things I've seen people add to their bashrc should have been window manager autostarts, or systemd user services, or belong in their /etc/profile as just being global environment variables, or should be executed once during boot and should hence be a startup service

just for comparison, starting my bash takes 70 ms, roughly. How long does your take? /usr/bin/time -f %e bash -i -c exit shows me 0.07. If yours takes long enough for you to notice, it's probably a good idea to remove things from your .bashrc

I haven't replicated my usual bash setup in this vm. So now it takes roughly 20ms.
But thanks for the info. I will keep that in mind!

very nice; I find it annoying when a new shell takes longer to start than it takes me to start typing commands into it :)
